# Mechanism for simplifying double reference counted pointers

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, encapsulation, void-pointers

I'm currently wrapping a C++ library into a language that stores wrapped memory as void pointers and does its own garbage collection. Internally each object has a struct that holds on to the void pointer, keeps track of the reference count, and cleans up the data when everything that references it goes out of scope. I have no control over this mechanism.

The construction in C++ looks something like this:

```
MyObject::MyObject(CoreObject this_)
{
   this_->data = new MyObjectData();
}
```

Then, whenever you want to access the data in your object, you static_cast to your datatype and do whatever you want to do:

```
std::string MyObject::getName(CoreObject this_)
{
    MyObjectData* myObject = static_cast<MyObjectData*>(this_->data);
    assert(myObject != NULL);
    return myObject->getName();
}
```

The ins and outs of the language are not really important, but that's just to give you an idea of how you wrap code in this language.

Now, the library I am wrapping uses boost::shared_ptr all over the place. This is partially to make python bindings easy to wrap as shared pointers fits quite well with python's internal reference counting. However, to leverage that in this new language, the only way I can think to ensure that the reference counting and garbage collection don't interfere with one another, is to have a double pointer mechanism, i.e. void pointer pointing to a shared pointer.

Doing this, the construction now looks like this:

```
MyObject::MyObject(CoreObject this_)
{
   this_->data = new boost::shared_ptr<MyObjectData>(new MyObjectData());
}
```

and dereferencing is even worse:

```
std::string MyObject::getName(CoreObject this_)
{
    boost::shared_ptr<MyObjectData>* myObject = static_cast<boost::shared_ptr<MyObjectData>*>(this_->data);
    assert(myObject != NULL);
    assert(*myObject != NULL);
    return (*myObject)->getName();
}
```

I've typedef'd the boost::shared_ptr specialisations, but it's still pretty clunky. I also tried to abstract away the shared pointer into a templated class, but realised fairly quickly that I was simply shifting the problem.

I was wondering if anyone had any suggestions for an encapsulation or a better mechanism for doing this?

Many thanks.